# TPM 2.0 and Asus Z170 Pro Gaming Motherboard

Tags: motherboard, tpm, asus

It doesn't look like my machine was built with a TPM. I am wondering whether I can get one to match this motherboard (**Asus Z170 Pro Gaming**) and where to find it. Would a TPM 2.0 for this board need to come from Asus, or are there other options?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @gregg: No, it is very common for desktop & server motherboards to have just a pin-header for connecting the discrete TPM, with the actual module being sold separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your motherboard is said to support PTT which is Intel's implementation of TPM within the CPU:

1. Press "Del" when the ASUS or ROG logo appears to enter the BIOS.
2. Go to the Advanced\PCH-FW Configuration page and click “Enable” on the "PTT” drop-down menu.
3. you'll get a warning.
   https://www.asus.com/microsite/motherboard/ASUS-motherboards-Win11-ready/

Answer (score 2):

> It doesn't look like my machine was built with a TPM. I am wondering whether I can get one to match this motherboard (Asus Z170 Pro Gaming) and where to find it. Would a TPM 2.0 for this board need to come from Asus, or are there other options?

**It is worth pointing out that 6th and 7th Generation Intel processors will not be supported by Windows 11.**

However, 6th and 7th Generation Intel processors, both support firmware based TPM solutions.  On an Intel motherboard it's known at PTT which will satisfy the TPM 2.0 requirement for Windows 11.  You can enable this functionality by updating your firmware to the current version.

According to the documentation provided by ASUS, the Z170 Pro Gaming is compatible with Windows 11 "under current testing", but the processors that are supported do not actually meet the system requirements for Windows 11.

[Windows 11 Supported Intel Processors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-intel-processors)

If you had a supported processor you would only have to enable the PTT feature within your firmware options.  **Additionally, your motherboard does not appear to support a discrete TPM device, but a discrete TPM device is unnecessary since your processor supports PTT.**

You can do that in the following tab within the firmware:

[image]

[image]

[Windows 11 Ready ASUS Motherboards](https://www.asus.com/microsite/motherboard/ASUS-motherboards-Win11-ready/)

[Windows 11 Supported AMD Processors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-amd-processors)

Comment: To clarify, OP's motherboad **does support a discrete TPM chip** -- the 14-1 slot for the chip is on the bottom of the board.

Comment: @Michael - The fact it supports a discreet TPM is irrelevant to what my answer is explaining.  Even with a discreet TPM the processor installed in the motherboard still is not supported, and at the end of the day, you can install Windows 11 without TPM support.

Comment: That's fine; I was just offering correction to your misstatement about the TPM chip itself.  =)